# Get index of a constructor using RegEx

Tags: java, regex

I want to find the index of a constructor in a `String`. I'm taking line by line from a `jtextArea` and I want to find the index of a constructor. But I want the index of `"("` and `")"`. Actually, I want to find the initial part and the ending part position of a parameter-list of javas class.

Example:

```
String clasname="test";
String firstlineoftextarea="test(6)";
```

Output:

> index of start=4; index of end=6;

I think I need to use RegEx.

Comment: Can a line contain several occurrences of `(` and `)` ?

Comment: @Dici i load .java file in to textarea .then read line by line so when i read a line which is constructor line i wanna find index of start and end of parameter list.line can contain anything valid in java.

Comment: Of course there is no `eval()` function in Java, but you can compile and load java code at runtime, this might be what you want

Comment: @msrd0 my target is drawing constructor chain programmatically.when i write a java class in jtextarea ,my program should draw the constructor chain .so i don't think about runtime .first i want to find start and end of a constructor .

Comment: So you just want to split up a string containing a constructor to the classname and the arguments?

Comment: @msrd0 i think yes.and i need index too.because i'm going to put arrows at the start of constructor and end of the constructor[i think there is different ways of drawing chain .in my case i put arrows start and end of a constructor ]

Comment: @programingbitch You have no guarantee the constructor will be written on only one line. You need to detect the beginning of a constructor and read lines until you find a closing bracket.

Comment: @Dici yes i think i can't guarantee .but my program is just for simple class .accuracy not want to be 100

Comment: Then Eran answer should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can use indexOf :

```
int first = firstlineoftextarea.indexOf("(");
int last = -1;
if (first >= 0)
    last = firstlineoftextarea.indexOf(")",first);
```

This would work if the line contains just one pair of "()". If it contains more than one, you can get the index of the first "(" the same way, and the index of the last ")" with `firstlineoftextarea.lastIndexOf(")",first)`;

Comment: that wouldn't exclude regular method calls.